# Is there a way to know at compile time, which version of an overloaded function has been chosen by the compiler to be called?

Tags: c++, overloading, overload-resolution

A possible way of doing this is to make the return type of the overloaded functions store the information of the specific function:

```
template<class _ret_t, class _func_t>
struct tpinf
{
    using ret_t = _ret_t;
    using func_t = _func_t;

    ret_t value;
};


tpinf<int, int(*)(double)> func(int n) { ... }
tpinf<int, int(*)(char)> func(char c) { ... }

int main()
{
    int n = 56;

    using resolved_function_type = decltype(func(n))::func_t;

    auto v = func(n).value; // access returned object

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is, I might want to know which overload is resolved of some predefined or standard functions, for that I have to rewrite those functions, which is not a good idea. So is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Overload resolution is done at compile time, not at run time, so your question's title is a bit misleading.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem to me. What is the actual problem you are having? The correct function is determined at compile time and the rules for that selection are well defined. I also don't directly see the need for the struct you are declaring, your template functions can return `auto`

Comment: you can pick one overload to be called manually. Though that you do not need to know which overload has been called is one of the reasons to supply overloads in the first place. Why do you need to know?

Comment: The compiler determines at compile-time which function to call by following an overload resolution algorithm. In principle anyone can follow the same algorithm and arrive at the same result.

Comment: "Know at compile-time" - as in inside of a template? Or just for yourself to better understand the code? The solution to the latter is "get a better IDE".

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Inside a function template.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, I know this could be done, but it would have been great if there was a simpler way.

Comment: Ok, then why do you need this? What function would you apply this to and why?

Comment: @AriesVictor simpler than what? Sorry, I am still confused about what you want. Is it selecting one overload? Thats what the answer shows and its as simple as it can get. Or do you want to determine what overload will be choosn by overload resolution when you call `f(n)` ? This isnt as simple, and it is unclear why you would need it.

Comment: If you need to know (and maybe to call a specific instance), then the functions shouldn't be overloaded to begin with. The whole point of overloading is that you don't really know (although of course, you can, by applying the compilers overload rules yourself); it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the address of an overloaded function in a context where which overload you want is unambiguous.

```
int func(int);
int func(char);

int main()
{
    int n = 56;

    int (*pfunc)(int) = func; // pfunc is a pointer to 'int func(int)'

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: not only ambiguity, but also implicit conversions pose a limit for this approach https://godbolt.org/z/dnxfo3WjW

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai hmm, the `decltype` there is kinda misleading

Comment: ok but this is manually picking an overload, this is of course possible. But OP wants to infer what overload is choosen by overload resolution. Thats why I liked the answer with the `decltype(n)`, it did what OP asked for, only with limitations. Now you need to know in advance what overload to pick